# LINQ: executing stored procedure, but skipping cursor within

Tags: linq, stored-procedures, cursor

I'm working on this wonky data project (C#/LINQ/MS SQL).  I receive a very poorly formatted dataset and I'm working at building up some meaningful reports with the data.  For one of the reports ("SwitchFlow"), I'm created a Stored Proc called "SwitchFlowGenerate".  It takes two params, the date of the report and the company of origin.

At the very end of the stored proc I ended up using a cursor (uck) to loop through the data to generate a customer count field value.

When I run the stored proc within management studio it works 100%.  When I had the stored proc to my LINQ-to-SQL and call it from a Visual Studio C# console app, it doesn't completely work...

From my app, the stored proc "SwitchFlowGenerate" populates the report table as it should, returns no error codes (in debug or production), but it appears to not execute the cursor portion of the stored proc (leaving the customer count field at zero).

I call the stored proc from MS SQL Management Studio simply like this:

**exec switchflowgenerate '03-13-2012', 'ace'**

From C#/LINQ I call it like this:

**db.SwitchFlowGenerate(DateTime.Now, ldc);**

(note: .Now is the same as above in MSMS)

The cursor portion of the code looks like this:

**--Update Customer Count column to reflect account switch movement

```
DECLARE @Adjust INT

SET @Adjust = 0

DECLARE @cc nvarchar(100)

DECLARE @stat nvarchar(100)

DECLARE SFC CURSOR FOR SELECT CustomerCount, [Status] FROM SwitchFlow WHERE ReportDate = @rptDate AND LDC = @ldc FOR UPDATE

OPEN SFC

FETCH SFC INTO @cc, @stat

WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)

    BEGIN

        IF @stat = 'Dropped' BEGIN SET @Adjust = -1 END

        IF @stat = 'Start' BEGIN SET @Adjust = 1 END

        IF @stat = 'In Queue - To Start' BEGIN SET @Adjust = 1 END

        IF @stat = 'In Queue - To Drop' BEGIN SET @Adjust = -1 END

        IF @stat = 'Reenrolling' BEGIN SET @Adjust = 1 END

        IF @stat = '#### SAME DAY ####' BEGIN SET @Adjust = 0 END


        SET @@StartingTotal = @@StartingTotal + @Adjust


        UPDATE [SwitchFlow] SET CustomerCount = @@StartingTotal WHERE CURRENT OF SFC

        FETCH SFC INTO @cc, @stat


    END

CLOSE SFC

DEALLOCATE SFC**

    Linq generates:
    Generating Data For: ACE on 3/13/2012

    EXEC @RETURN_VALUE = [dbo].[SwitchFlowGenerate] @rptDate = @p0, @ldc = @p1

    -- @p0: Input DateTime (Size = -1; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [3/13/2012 9:56:59 AM]

    -- @p1: Input NVarChar (Size = 4000; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [ACE]

    -- @RETURN_VALUE: Output Int (Size = -1; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [Null]

    -- Context: SqlProvider(Sql2008) Model: AttributedMetaModel Build: 4.0.30319.1
```

Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated ~especially if someone has an idea of how to accomplish that without a cursor.

Thanks!!
TK

Comment: What does Linq-to-SQL's translation of your sproc code look like? Also instead of a cursor you could try using a WHILE loop.

Comment: [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.FunctionAttribute(Name="dbo.SwitchFlowGenerate")]
  public int SwitchFlowGenerate([global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ParameterAttribute(DbType="DateTime")] System.Nullable<System.DateTime> rptDate, [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ParameterAttribute(DbType="NVarChar(10)")] string ldc)
  {
   IExecuteResult result = this.ExecuteMethodCall(this, ((MethodInfo)(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod())), rptDate, ldc);
   return ((int)(result.ReturnValue));
  }

Comment: Sorry I meant the SQL code which LINQ itself generates. Also for best formatting you can just append your code sample to your original question above.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: Thanks Darth and Marc for the formatting comments.  I'm a noob here when it comes to posting, but have used you guys for years as a source of help!  Thanks so much!

Comment: I think you should use `db.SwitchFlowGenerate(DateTime.Today, ldc);` (so Today in stead of Now).